# How to increase the font size of SWT dialog title

Tags: java, shell, dialog, swt

How the font size of dialog title (eg. "Example SWT Shell") can be increased? setFont method of shell does not increase the size of title.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The dialog title is drawn by the OS Window Manager. SWT does not provide a way the font used for this.